# broadleaf demo app help tomcat external setup with mysql connectivity

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat7, broadleaf-commerce

Hi dear I have followed the steps mentioned in http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/switch-to-mysql-tutorial but I am getting exceptions that are some thing like belows:

```
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
[artifact:mvn]  ... 28 more
[artifact:mvn] Sep 03, 2015 1:13:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
[artifact:mvn] WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
[artifact:mvn] Sep 03, 2015 1:13:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
[artifact:mvn] INFO: Set web app root system property: 'site.root' = [E:\f drive\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\eclipse-workspace\DemoSite\site\src\main\webapp\]
[artifact:mvn] Sep 03, 2015 1:13:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
[artifact:mvn] INFO: Initializing log4j from [E:\f drive\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\eclipse-workspace\DemoSite\site\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\log4j.xml]
[artifact:mvn] Sep 03, 2015 1:13:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
[artifact:mvn] INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[artifact:mvn] Sep 03, 2015 1:13:33 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
[artifact:mvn] WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
[artifact:mvn] java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:631)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:485)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:539)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
[artifact:mvn]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1421)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:802)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1105)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:661)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:471)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:148)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[artifact:mvn] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
[artifact:mvn]  ... 70 more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying to an external Tomcat (not using the ant task) then you need to download the mysql-connector jar (from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36) and put it in your Tomcat lib directory.